# How to create global controller to all views?

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to angular and JS and do not know how to implement very simple behavior. So... I have an angular-route module and all my views are changed with ng-view directive. Here is the declaration

```
<body>
    <div class="row main" ng-view> </div> 
<body>
```

I have all controllers connected to those views. Also I have one common controller to all views, I check cookie in that controller. How to call that controller automatically in all other views without dependency on that controller from others?

I tried to put it in   but it is called only once on the index page.

Comment: Check this out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22480738/angular-ui-router-call-parent-controller-function-from-child-controller

Comment: the question for me would be is it really a controller that you need. As i understand you do want to execute some code (for cookie checking) for every page, what is probably not needed. If you want to check if the user has a cookie i would recommend doing this in the app code.

Comment: You mean in server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="globalController">
        <div class="row main" ng-view> </div> 
    </div>
<body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/k2H8BsTCVh24nbR07GjP?p=preview

Comment: This doesn't help. This div will not updated when angular change the view.

Comment: @user1315599 you are right but you can periodically check for cookie with $interval to overcome this limitation.

Comment: I need to check cookie each time user change the view. Because information on the view depends if user was log in.

Comment: @user1315599 i updated my example to fit better to your needs.

Comment: this is absolutely the same as before

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/nl5OH51pARRVESEoZ9Ys I want the alert shows every time you open new link

Comment: Look at my plunker and check the developer console.it will show a log message while you navigating.

Answer (score 0):

A controller, by definition, is meant to prepare the data to be passed to the view.

I would recommend you to do this with a service instead.

This service could then be accessed by whatever view you are in.

You could imagine, for example, to implement a resolver in you $routeProvider.when which will read the Cookie from this service.
$route also trigger events whenever the view is changing, will change or has changed. Try to leverage this, this is really powerful.